# Mapping to custom types in NHibernate 3.2

Tags: nhibernate

I have just started to use NHibernate 3.2 with its new Conformist API, having used previous versions with Fluent a while back. The basic stuff seems fine but I am currently struggling with trying to map a string to a custom type.

In this specific case, I have a string which is a semi-colon separated list of roles in a column on one of my tables. When I get it out, I want it to be mapped into a "RoleSet" custom object that I have created by passing the string value from the database into its constructor.

I have created a IUserType but I cannot see how to tell it to use it.

Previously with Fluent I would have done this in my map class:

```
Map(x => x.Roles).CustomType<RoleSetType>();
```

Is there an equivalent way to do this is in the new API?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give this a try...

```
Property(x => x.Roles, x => x.Type(typeof(RoleSetType), null));
```